# Stuck in a redirect loop in Flask application

Tags: python, html, web, flask

I am using the following @app.before_request statement in my flask app.

```
Checker = False
@app.before_request
def requireLogin():
    redirect_routes = ['split']
    allowed_routes = ['login', 'signup', 'split']
    #to force user to login and signup page
    if request.endpoint not in redirect_routes and 'username' not in session and Checker == False:
        print('Start')
        return redirect('/split') 
    elif request.endpoint not in allowed_routes and 'username' not in session and Checker == True:
        return redirect('/login')
```

When I do flask run, The following two lines loop until I get a redirect error.
[24/Jul/2020 13:14:01] "[32mGET /split HTTP/1.1[0m" 302 -   and Start

Interestingly, if I add login to redirect_routes, and replace return redirect('/split') with return redirect('/login'), this loop doesn't occur, and the app functions normally.

The following is /split

```
@app.route('/split', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Splitter():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Stop')
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        print(username)
        print(password)
        
        return redirect('/split')

    else:
        return render_template('split.html')
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. I needed to rename my function Splitter to split.